# Does PHP has interface for print_r or var_dump?

Tags: php, oop, interface

PHP has a lot of built in handy interfaces for usage with different functions. I wonder, is there a interface to handle output for `print_r` or `var_dump`?

If there's not, is there another function or/with interface for displaying structured data from class (except `__toString`)?

Comment: Both `print_r` and `var_dump` are intended for revealing the **raw** structure of objects, therefore there's no interfacy hook for overriding. The closest is possibly JsonSerializable; but you'd still need a customized output method.

Comment: are you asking to show the print_r in a structured manner??

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes yes.
@mario `The closest is possibly JsonSerializable; but you'd still need a customized output method.`
That's seems worth to try. Thanks!

Comment: Will you try adding html tag <pre>. It will be like echo '<pre>'; print_r($array); echo '</pre>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use print_r and then just copy the output and paste it into an array beautifier(google it) it will make a nice readable output. Its by far the easiest way to check array data within php without a huge amount of work. I use it all the time :)

Good luck!

Comment: Using a debugger and set breakpoints is much easier and safer since you don't need to modify code to get a result.

Comment: Assumed we were talking as if debugger was out of the question else why even ask the question but good point.

Comment: @Bart I tried XDebug yesterday with MacGDBp.app, however breakpoints didn't worked for me :( I mean, they *literally* didn't worked

Comment: @LukeLad that's not really a solution.

Comment: @Bart UPD: I actually could make MacGDBp.app work with breakpoints.

Comment: It's not an answer. It's comment.

Answer (score 2):

php `5.6.0` added the [`__debugInfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.debuginfo) method. It's not an interface, just a method to define on any object. Add this method to set the results of `var_dump`.